# Difference between "地主" and "家主", and their relationship with 不動産屋？

Tags: word-choice

I just learned a new word, "地主{じぬし}, whose definition in my web dictionary, and paper dictionary, is *landlord, land owner*.

"家主{やぬし}" is surely the word that native English speakers would use for the *landlord* of the apartment where they live. I've never heard anything else.

- Because "地" means "land, soil", is "地主" like the *owner of a plot of land*? Whether there is a house on that plot of land is not relevant?
- Most "家主" work as employees for large companies that own buildings with apartments in them? In that, your typical "家主" does not own the apartments that they manage?
- If so, then a 不動産屋 would introduce me to a 地主 to exchange cash for her / his land? I would be introduced to a 家主 to ask if it is ok to live in the apartments that he/she manages?

Am I correct about this?

Comment: Did you mean to write "native Japanese speakers"?

Comment: @snailboat no. What I mean is that when I, and many other native English speakers who I known, expressed in Japanese our perception of what a "landlord" is, we would say "yanushi".  "Yanshi" had been a direct mapping to "landlord", but now I see it is not that simple.

Comment: Indeed, because native Japanese speakers prefer 大家{おおや}(さん).

Comment: @broccoliforest I was just confused, because when I read the question, I figured that the word native speakers of *English* would choose was irrelevant . . . I guess I understand now.

Comment: @snailboat Actually, 家主 is a word you wouldn't see very much outside something legal...

Comment: @snailboat I was just saying I'd thought "家主" <---> "landlord" a simple/direct translation. Non-Japanese around me spoke as such, and natives never corrected me. I am so happy to know about 大家、家主、地主 now! I'm glad I asked.

Comment: @David_W. It's a good question :-)  I just didn't understand what you meant at first.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

地主 is an owner of the land, while 家主 is an owner of housing. Land and housing are <s>separate</s> objects of separate ownerships in Japan. If you rent a land from someone, he/she is 地主 for you. If you build a house on that land and rent the house to someone else, you are 家主 for him/her.

When you are seeking a house, 不動産屋 wouldn't introduce you to a 地主, instead, they would to a 家主. 地主 is irrelevant in this contract.